# NSToolBar increase height

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there a way to increase a height of NSToolBar in Mac Os. I need height 70 px but I have 53 px. I didn't find any appropriate way to do it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Not sure why you wanna do that, but have you thought about using an NSView instead and line up a bunch of buttons instead of customizing NSToolBar?

Comment: I have a functionality for customizing on this toolbar, so using NSView instead is not a way for me.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think the stock NSToolbar can be resized... BUT you could just go with an NSMatrix or a single-line UICollectionView

Comment: Hmm. How can I apply them to NSToolbar?

Comment: instead of a toolbar, use a matrix or a collection view but you will loose the ability to modify it

Comment: The ability to modify it is very important for me. Since a lot of functionality was already written. I can see that Finder toolbar is the size I need. Is there a way to make it that size?

Comment: @AlexanderSlabinsky Finder's toolbar is the default height of a toolbar created in IB